# sort first numbers before the space

Tags: python, sorting

I greet everyone I need help and thank you so much

so I have this code

```
alphabet = {
    "A": 1,
    "Á": 1,
    "Ä": 1,
    "Ă": 1,
    "á": 1,
    "a": 1,
    "B": 2,
    "b": 2,
    "C": 3,
    "Č": 3,
    "č": 3,
    "c": 3,
    "D": 4,
    "d": 4,
    "Ď": 4,
    "ď": 4,
    "E": 5,
    "É": 5,
    "e": 5,
    "é": 5,
    "ě": 5,
    "F": 6,
    "f": 6,
    "G": 7,
    "g": 7,
    "H": 8,
    "h": 8,
    "I": 9,
    "i": 9,
    "í": 9,
    "Í": 9,
    "J": 10,
    "j": 10,
    "k": 11,
    "K": 11,
    "L": 12,
    "l": 12,
    "M": 13,
    "N": 14,
    "O": 15,
    "ó": 15,
    "P": 16,
    "Q": 17,
    "R": 18,
    "ř": 18,
    "S": 19,
    "T": 20,
    "Ť": 20,
    "ť": 20,
    "U": 21,
    "V": 22,
    "W": 23,
    "X": 24,
    "Y": 25,
    "ý": 25,
    "m": 13,
    "n": 14,
    "ň": 14,
    "o": 15,
    "Ó": 15,
    "p": 16,
    "q": 17,
    "r": 18,
    "Ř": 18,
    "s": 19,
    "Š": 19,
    "š": 19,
    "t": 20,
    "u": 21,
    "ú": 21,
    "Ú": 21,
    "ů": 21,
    "v": 22,
    "V": 22,
    "w": 23,
    "x": 24,
    "Ý": 25,
    "y": 25,
    "z": 26,
    "ž": 26,
    "Z": 26,
    "Ž": 26,
    "1": 0,
    "2": 0,
    "3": 0,
    "4": 0,
    "5": 0,
    "6": 0,
    "7": 0,
    "8": 0,
    "9": 0,
    "0": 0,
    ",": 0,
    ".": 0,
    ",": 0,
    ":": 0,
    "?": 0,
    "=": 0,
    "+": 0,
    "-": 0,
    "ˇ": 0,
    "!": 0,
    "„": 0,
    "“": 0,
    ";": 0,
    "»": 0,
    "«": 0,
    "\t": 0,
    "'": 0,
    "(": 0,
    ")": 0,
    '"': 0,
    '\n': 0,
    "`": 0,
    "´": 0,
    " ": 0
}


def gematria(word):
    result = 0
    for char in word:
        result += alphabet[char]
    return result

with open('3.txt',encoding="utf8") as f:
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        line = f.readline()
        print(gematria(line),line, file=open(""+str("66")+".txt", "a",encoding="utf8"))

with open('66.txt',encoding="utf8") as infile, open('outpu.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if not line.strip(): continue  
        outfile.write(line)
with open("outpu.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("yourfile.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip("\n") != "0 ":
            f.write(line)
```

and need the file file text to arrange the numbers in a row in the diagram

the script works by opening the file 3.text there go on each line of similar sentences

input

```
11:1:2 Thank you for your help
11:1:1 and here is the text and the others continue the same lines
```

and this script eats da gematriie and need to sort the first came before the gap sort method but I do not know how to do it and saved it to a file

output

```
553 11:1:1 and here is the text and the others continue the same lines
274 1:1:2 Thank you for your help
```

I want it to be sorted from the smallest to the largest numbers before the space

```
274 1:1:2 Thank you for your help
553 11:1:1 and here is the text and the others continue the same lines
```

Comment: Don't `print` the lines, store them for example in a list of tuples `(value, line)` and sort this list. More generally, don't print outputs, put them in some structure in order to be able to manipulate them.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille here new in programming i don't know how to do it could you make a code for sort? I don't know how to do many of my attempts failed thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the lines and calculate the value, then sort them and write the file:

```
def gematria(word):
    # using a "generator expression"
    return sum(alphabet[char] for char in word)

with open('input.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
      # A generator expression that stores a sorted tuple of 
      # the calculation and the stripped line.
      lines = sorted((gematria(line),line.strip()) for line in f)

with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for num,line in lines:
        # Looks like you wanted to skip blank lines
        if line:
            print(num, line, file=f)
```